# What's the proper way to parse text with tag using Rust nom?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I want to parse text with tag. For example, for the string `aa<haha>test 1 2 3</haha> string 2`, the result should be the string `aa`, the tag `haha` with content `test 1 2 3`, and a string  `string 2`. Below is my code. It works for now. But I'm sure it's not the best way to solve the problem. Could anyone help me to find a better way to solve the problem or at least simplify the code? Thanks.

```
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::{*};
use nom::IResult;
use nom::sequence::{delimited, separated_pair};


#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ElementType {
    Text(String),
    Tag(String, String),
}


fn parse_element_type_text(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, ElementType> {
    let (remaining, text) = take_till(|c: char| c == '<')(input)?;
    if text.is_empty() {
        Err(nom::Err::Error(nom::error::Error::new(input, nom::error::ErrorKind::Eof)))
    } else {
        Ok((remaining, ElementType::Text(text.to_string())))
    }
}


fn parse_element_type_tag(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, ElementType> {
    let (left, tag_name) = delimited(
        tag("<"),
        take_until(">"),
        tag(">"),
    )(input)?;
    let (left, content) = take_until("</")(left)?;
    let (left, tag_name2) = delimited(
        tag("</"),
        tag(tag_name),
        tag(">"),
    )(left)?;

    Ok((left, ElementType::Tag(tag_name.to_string(), content.to_string())))
}


fn parse_element(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<ElementType>> {
    let mut elements = vec![];
    let mut input = input;

    loop {
        let original_input = input;
        match alt((parse_element_type_tag, parse_element_type_text))(input) {
            Ok((remaining_input, element)) => {
                elements.push(element);
                input = remaining_input;
            }
            Err(_) => break,
        }
        if original_input == input {
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok((input, elements))
}


fn main() {
    let text = r#"<foo>some more text</foo> even more text!<tag2>test haha</tag2>"#;
    let result = parse_element(text);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem with just `take_until("</")`, what if there are nested tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, you should always include links to the playground with questions like this. If you don't know, the rust playground can be found [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/) and allows one to run code in the browser and to share it with others. You can share specific snippets via the share button in the top right, and then saving the permalink.

The main problem with your approach that it doesn't deal with recursive tag structures. Tags may contain other sub-tags, correct? If so, you run into the problem with `take_until("</")` that is mentioned by [cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25) - it will skip any other tags:

```rust
fn main() {
    let text = r#"<foo><bar>hello</bar></foo>"#;
    let result = parse_element(text);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f11a243064ee0e151dc86408fa3e642a)

The above snippet returns `Ok(("<foo><bar>hello</bar></foo>", []))` as the closing tag `"<\bar>"` does not match the opening tag `"<foo>"`.

The problem runs deeper than just the use of `take_until`, however. In order to support nested tags, your enum must actually be recursively defined:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ElementType {
    Text(String),
    Tag(String, Vec<ElementType>),
}
```

(note that the compiler allows this because while `ElementType` is containing itself recursively, it is behind a `Vec<ElementType>`, which acts the same way a `Box<ElementType>` would - the actual inner `ElementType` is stored on the heap, with the original type merely containing a pointer to children `ElementType`s)

This is because tags may contain any amount of sub-tags. Thus, parsing must be done recursively:

```rust
fn parse_element_type_tag(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, ElementType> {
    let (left, tag_name) = delimited(
        tag("<"),
        take_until(">"),
        tag(">"),
    )(input)?;
    let (left, content) = parse_element(left)?;
    let (left, tag_name2) = delimited(
        tag("</"),
        tag(tag_name),
        tag(">"),
    )(left)?;

    Ok((left, ElementType::Tag(tag_name.to_string(), content)))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd718722832e77b55a51ca36dcd5dac6)

The downside to using Vec is that it becomes more complex to traverse the tree created, which can be seen in the printed value of the example using recursive tags:

`Ok(("", [Tag("foo", [Tag("bar", [Text("hello")])])]))`

This could be remedied by adding additional enum variants for tags that contain nothing and tags that contain only a single element, however this would depend highly upon your use-case, and may make things even more complex.

Comment: Thanks my friend for your precious time! I really learnt a lot from your answer!